# How to perform differential backups with tar?

Tags: backup, tar

I know I can perform progressive (incremental) backups with `tar` using snapshots, I am doing something like this for the directory I want to create a backup for:

```
tar cpf progressive.tar --listed-incremental=snapshot /home/user/dir
```

However, can I do differential backups with `tar` instead of progressive ones?

I know the `--diff` is used for this task, but it's not clear to me how to do the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do **automated** differential backups with tar using the --diff operation mode. This is because the --diff operation mode will only look for differences between files **already** in the tar file and the files of the file system. If a file that resides in the tar file is missing in the file system tar will give you this message:

```
tar: etc/test.txt: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

If the content of a file already in the tar file gets changed, tar will print:

```
etc/test.txt: Mod time differs
etc/test.txt: Size differs
```

If there is a new file in the file system tar will give you no information. The same is true for the `--update` operation mode. It only checks for files already in the archiv.

I found some solutions for doing differential backups with tar using the `--newer` parameter relaying on date/time informations of the last full or differential backup. Other solutions stores metadata of the backups and doing differential backups using this metadata.